# Is there a way to configure Camel Dead Letter Channel to propagate the exception to the route consumer?

Tags: apache-camel

In Apache Camel Dead Letter Channel [docs](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html), the following is stated:

> The Dead Letter Channel lets you control behaviors including
>   redelivery, whether to propagate the thrown Exception to the caller
>   (the handled option), and where the (failed) Exchange should now be
>   routed to.

Note it states 'the handled option' as configurable. After reviewing the [Javadocs](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/DeadLetterChannelBuilder.html) for the DSL builder there is no evident way to configure `handled` to be `false`.

This Camel [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9555) suggests in the past setting `deadLetterHandleNewException` to false would result in this behavior, but it is not clear if after the fix, there is still a way to have the DLC propagate exceptions back to the caller (in my specific case a file consumer)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do like this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .handled(false)
  .to("myDeadletterQueue");
```

Comment: That could work but I'm more interested in the behavior and configuration of the DLC error handler by itself

Comment: @CamiloCrespo I am trying to figure that out as well, did you find a solution?

Comment: @CamiloCrespo : did you get this to work? I am looking for a solution for this too.